# regular expresions in firebase.json rewrites

Tags: regex, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

When using [firebase with functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) it is possible to use regular expressions to match incoming requests and based on the match use a specific function sharing the same endpoint? for example, I am trying this:

```
{
    "hosting": {
        "rewrites": [
            {
                "source": "/^([0-9a-f]{2}[:-]){15}([0-9a-f]{2})$",
                "function": "getFingerprint"
            },
            {
                "source": "/*",
                "function": "callNew"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I would like to match urls like:

`http://test.firebaseapp.com/b4:e8:b4:ec:4a:36:76:4b:04:4a:83:c9:47:d4:c8:70`

If the request matches the defined regular expression then use the function `getFingerprint` if not,  in my try to implement a "catch-all", I am using `/*`.

The only pattern that works at the moment is `/*`, but can't find a way to make this one to work:

```
^([0-9a-f]{2}[:-]){15}([0-9a-f]{2})$
```

Therefore wondering if is possible to use any regex within the `firebase.json` file for configuring custom rewrites and share endpoints, for example, `/` in this case or as an alternative better to have a unique resource and then split the URL path to retrieve the paths as parameters

Comment: try this   ([0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}:?)

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation on [Firebase Hosting rewrite rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites):

> A `source` specifying a [glob pattern](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#glob_pattern_matching)

Glob patterns are a subset of regular expressions, and for example I don't it supports the `^` and `$` terminator expressions that you use.

Comment: It now seems to allow regex as well: "Use source to specify a glob (recommended) /
Use regex to specify a RE2 regular expression."